# Python Uno Game

Tags: python, nameerror

I am trying to play uno

try this: `if __name__ == "main": main()` ,Now ı get this error ; NameError: name 'Deck' is not defined

```
import random

class UnoCard:
    def __init__(self, c,n):
        self.color = c
        self.num = n
    def __str__(self):
        if self.c == 0:
            return "green" + str(self.n)
        if self.c == 1:
            return "yellow" + str(self.n)
        if self.c == 2:
            return "blue" + str(self.n)
        if self.c == 3:
            return "red" + str(self.n)
    def canPlay(self,other):
        if (self.num == other.num) or (self.color == other.color):
            return True
        return False 

class CollectionOfUnoCards:
    def __init__(self):
        self.l = []
    def addCard (self,c):
        self.l.append(c)
    def __str__(self):
        if(self.l):
            col_str = ""
            for i in range (0, len(self.l)):
                col_str = col_str + ' ' + str(self.l[i])
            return col_str
    def makeDeck(self):
        for num in range (1,10):
            for color in ["Yellow", "Red", "Blue", "Green"]:
                newcard = UnoCard(color,num)
                Deck.addCard(newcard)
                Deck.addCard(newcard)


    def shuffle(self):
        shuffle = random.randint(0,73)

    def getNumCards(self):
        return len(CollectionOfUnoCards)

    def getTopCard(self):
        return CollectionOfUnoCards[0]

    def canPlay(self, other):
        for card in self.l:
            if(card.canPlay(other)):
                return True
        return False        

    def getCard(self,index):
        return makeDeck(CollectionOfUnoCards)


class Uno:
    def __init__(self):
        self.Deck = CollectionOfUnoCards()
        self.Deck.makeDeck()
        self.Deck.shuffle()
        self.hand1 = CollectionOfUnoCards()
        self.hand2 = CollectionOfUnoCards()
        for i in range(7):
            self.hand1.Collection.append(deck.Collection.pop( ))
            self.hand1.Collection.append(deck.Collection.pop( ))

    def playGame(self):
        self.hand1.l.pop()
        self.lastPlayedCard = hand1.l.pop()
        while(True):
            self.playTurn(1)
            self.playTurn(2)
            if len(self.hand1.l) == 0 or len(self.hand2.l) == 0 :
                if len(self.hand1.l) == 0:
                    print("Player1 is winner")
                elif len(self.hand2.l) == 0:
                    print("player2 is winner")
                else:
                    print("The game ends in a draw")
                return False


    def playTurn(self, Player):
        if Player == 1:
            if canPlay(lastPlayedCard):
                hand1.pop()
                lastPlayedCard = hand1.pop()
            else: 
                hand1.Collection.append(deck.Collection.pop())
        else: 
            if canPlay(lastPlayedCard):
                hand2.pop()
                lastPlayedCard = hand2.pop()
            else: 
                hand2.Collection.append(deck.Collection.pop())

    def printResult(self):
        print (hand1)
        print (hand2)

def main():
    my_game = Uno()
    my_game.playGame()
```

I wrote in Anaconda on Windows 10.
The program closes automatically when I run it.
I'm not getting any output..

Comment: `Deck.addCard(newcard)` cannot be done. You have no Deck there, plus you should only capitalize Classes, not fields

Comment: You need to learn to follow your program's execution. From `my_game = Uno()`, it calls the Uno class' `__init__`, which calls `makeDeck()`, which has `Deck.addCard(newcard)` but `Deck` is never defined anywhere.

Comment: The uno tag is inappropriate for this question. The uno tag refers to the component model of OpenOffice.org, not the card game.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you're building the deck incorrectly.

You have no Deck variable within the makeDeck function. Rather you want to add the card to itself like so

```
def makeDeck(self):
    duplicates = 2
    for num in range (1,10):
        for color in ["Yellow", "Red", "Blue", "Green"]:
            newcard = UnoCard(color,num)
            for _ in range(duplicates):
                self.addCard(newcard)
```

Also, `color` must be a number not a string for the `self.c == 0` lines to work, which should actually say `self.color == 0`. There is no `self.c` or `self.n`

Note: UNO has skips, reverse, and wilds

Comment: Thanks for your answer but now ı get this error;   
'CollectionOfUnoCards' object has no attribute 'Collection'    and when ı  write 

self.color == c

ı get this error; 

AttributeError: 'UnoCard' object has no attribute 'color'

Comment: Did you write this code, or copy it? I don't think we should be helping with each and every incorrect line. For example, what did you expect this to do? `self.hand1.Collection.append(deck.Collection.pop( ))`? Can you point me at the Collection variable?

Comment: ı wrote this code. and it's create list to playgame function. if it's not written 
at line82 give pop from empty list  error. so program is will not work

Comment: Okay, so I ask, where is `Collection` from the CollectionOfUnoCards class defined?

Comment: And not sure I understand why `getCard` would return a whole new deck

Comment: yeah maybe it's  unnecessary. and ı think it's not defined :/

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/204251/discussion-between-can-lgu-and-cricket-007).